# python request REST API for multiple URLS

Tags: python

I'm teaching myself python by doing projects and I'm trying to request an API for store locations.  There are 6000 stores, but the API only allows for 1 location at a time.  As you can see in my code below, it is not very efficient.  What is a more efficient way to request 1-6000 URLs? For URLs starting at http://www.ecommerce.com/stores?serviceTypes=-1&storeIds=1 and ending at http://www.ecommerce.com/stores?serviceTypes=-1&storeIds=6000

I tried using github.com/ross/requests-futures, but haven't been able to get it to work

```
import requests, json
from requests import Session

session = Session()
url = ['http://www.ecommerce.com/stores?serviceTypes=-1&storeIds=%s' % n for n in xrange(1, 6000)]

header = {
    'access_token': '12341234',
    'country_code': 'US',
    'language_code': 'en'}
r = session.get(url, headers=header)

dump = r.text

f = open("myfile.txt", "w")
f.write(dump)
```

Currently I get the following error: requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found

What I'm essentially trying to do is the code below:

```
url = "http://www.ecommerce.com/stores?serviceTypes=-1&storeIds=1"
url2 = "http://www.ecommerce.com/stores?serviceTypes=-1&storeIds=2"
url3 = "http://www.ecommerce.com/stores?serviceTypes=-1&storeIds=3"
header = {
    'access_token': '12341234',
    'country_code': 'US',
    'language_code': 'en'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
r2 = requests.get(url2, headers=header)
r3 = requests.get(url3, headers=header)

dump = r.text + r2.text + r3.text

f = open("myfile.txt", "w")
    f.write(dump)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried creating URLs and making requests dynamically? You could create URLs and make requests on the fly using a counter variable:

```
header = {
    'access_token': '12341234',
    'country_code': 'US',
    'language_code': 'en'}

for i in range(0, 6001):
    url = "http://www.ecommerce.com/stores?serviceTypes=-1&storeIds=" + str(i)
    r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    # Do what you want with r.text here
```

You may have issues making all these requests depending on the API's request limit.

As for the InvalidSchema error, make sure that your URL is formatted correctly.